# Notify celery task of worker shutdown

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using celery 2.4.1 with python 2.6, the rabbitmq backend, and django. I would like my task to be able to clean up properly if the worker shuts down.  As far as I am aware you cannot supply a task destructor so I tried hooking into the [worker_shutdown](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutdown) signal.

Note: [AbortableTask](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html) only works with the database backend so I cant use that.

```
from celery.signals import worker_shutdown

@task
def mytask(*args)

  obj = DoStuff()

  def shutdown_hook(*args):
     print "Worker shutting down"
     # cleanup nicely
     obj.stop()

  worker_shutdown.connect(shutdown_hook)

  # blocking call that monitors a network connection
  obj.stuff()
```

However, the shutdown hook never gets called. Ctrl-C'ing the worker doesnt kill the task and I have to manually kill it from the shell.

So if this is not the proper way to go about it, how do I allow tasks to shutdown gracefully?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`worker_shutdown` is only sent by the `MainProcess`, not the child pool workers.
All `worker_*` signals `except for worker_process_init`, refer to the `MainProcess`.

> However, the shutdown hook never gets called. Ctrl-C'ing the worker
>   doesn't kill the task and I have to manually kill it from the shell.

The worker never terminates a task under normal (warm) shutdown.
Even if a task takes days to complete, the worker won't complete shutdown
until it's completed.  You can set `--soft-time-limit`, or `--time-limit` to
to tell the instance when it's ok to terminate the task.

So to add any kind of process cleanup process you first need to
make sure that the tasks can actually complete.  As the cleanup wouldn't
be called before that happens.

To add a cleanup step to the pool worker processes you can use
something like:

```
from celery import platforms
from celery.signals import worker_process_init

def cleanup_after_tasks(signum, frame):
    # reentrant code here (see http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html)

def install_pool_process_sighandlers(**kwargs):
    platforms.signals["TERM"] = cleanup_after_tasks
    platforms.signals["INT"] = cleanup_after_tasks

worker_process_init.connect(install_pool_process_sighandlers)
```

Comment: @RomanPodlinov - look at the Celery docs for ``revoke()`` - you can optionally send a signal which the worker can catch in order to clean up.

Comment: I don't get it. Is there any signal being emitted after `--soft-time-limit` is over? If so, which one?

Comment: Note that this is ancient, and more recent versions of celery can use signals for this. 
 See https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutting-down and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481656/237091.

Answer (score 0):

Use the worker_shutting_down signal.
See https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutting-down and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481656/237091 for an example.