# How to Abort Celery Task upon deploy to Heroku

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

When my new versions of my django application are deployed to heroku, the workers are forced to be restarted. I have some long running tasks which should perform some cleanup prior to being killed.

I have tried registering a worker_shutdown hook which doesn't every seem to get called.

I have also tried the answer in [Notify celery task of worker shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138642/notify-celery-task-of-worker-shutdown) but i am unclear of how to abort a given task from within this context as calling celery.task.control.active() throws an exception (celery is no longer running).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the deployment maybe you can run a script that does a [Control.broadcast](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.broadcast) to a custom command that you can [register beforehand](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#writing-your-own-remote-control-commands) and only after receiving the required replies (you'd have to implement that logic) you'd continue the deployment (or raise a TimeoutException)?

Also, celery already has a [predefined command for shutdown](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.worker.control.html#celery.worker.control.shutdown) which I'm guessing you could overload in your instance or Subclass of worker. Commands have the advantage of being passed a Panel instance which allows you access to [the consumer](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/internals/reference/celery.worker.consumer.html#celery.worker.consumer.Consumer). That should expose a lot of control right there...