# Notify celery task to stop during worker shutdown

Tags: python, celery

I'm using celery 3.X and RabbitMQ backend. From time to time it needs to restart celery (to push a new source code update to the server). But there is a task with big loop and try/catch inside of the loop; it can takes a few hours to accomplish the task. Nothing critical will happen if I will stop it and will restart it later.

QUESTION: The problem is every time after I stopped the workers (via sudo service celeryd stop) I have to KILL the task manually (via **kill -9**); the task **ignores SIGTERM** from worker. I've read throw Celery docs & Stackoverflow but I can't find working solution. Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138642/notify-celery-task-of-worker-shutdown?rq=1

Comment: @venkatesh-bachu I saw this, but it's a different case. That post about how to make CLEANING after task is complied. My question is how to stop/terminate a long (think as infinite) loop in the task when I stop the worker.

Comment: ps auxww | grep 'celeryd' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 with this command you can kill all process at a time, if you want use this command with fab otherwise you can restart the mechine after push the code to mechine if you want

Comment: @venkatesh-bachu Yes, I use this, but it's more like a 'hack'. I want to find permanent solution of my problem :)

Comment: I do server restart after every time code deploy

Comment: @VenkateshBachu This is not a solution for a distributed environment with autoscaling, for example. Rebooting is rarely a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the QUIT signal will [stop workers immediately](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#process-signals): `sudo service celeryd stop -QUIT`

If the CELERY_ACKS_LATE setting is set to True, tasks that were running when the worker stopped will run again when the worker starts back up.

Comment: That is a known bug that will hopefully be fixed in Celery 4.0.3 ... What happens is that even though tasks DO finish, they do not acknowledge it (when acks_late is True)...

Answer (score -1):

Celery is not intended to run long tasks cause it blocks the worker for your task only. I recommend re-arranging your logic, making the task invoke itself instead of making the loop. Once shutdown is in progress, your current task will complete and will resume right at the same point where it stopped before celery shutdown.

Also, having task split into chunks, you will be able to divert the task to another worker/host which is probably what you would like to do in the future.