# How to send a message to a running task on worker shutdown?

Tags: celery

I have a task that can take hours to complete.  However, it can be signaled to cleanly exit ASAP by setting a flag in memcached.  The task polls the flag periodically and when it is found the task saves its state and exits cleanly.  This all works fine if I just set the flag in the cache manually.

I'd like to use this to be able to shutdown the worker in a timely fashion, I just need to know where to put the flag-setting logic.  Here's what I've tried:

#### `worker_shutdown` handler

I tried putting it in a [`worker_shutdown`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutdown) handler but it looks like that only gets called *after* all tasks complete, so it doesn't help with shutting down my long-running task.

#### Signal handler via `celery.platforms.signals`

I tried attaching TERM and INT signal handlers using the `celery.platforms.signals` interface but my handler is never called:

```py
@worker_init.connect
def handle_worker_init(*args, **kwargs):
    platforms.signals["TERM"] = handle_worker_shutdown
    platforms.signals["INT"] = handle_worker_shutdown


def handle_worker_shutdown(*args, **kwargs):
    logger.info("Setting database cleanup stop flag to save our ship")
    database_cleanup_stop()
```

I also tried doing it in `worker_process_init` but my handler still isn't called. (And even if it was called it would be kind of obnoxious since every worker process would presumably be setting the flag, but I only need to set it once.  Harmless, but obnoxious.)

---

Is there any other signal where I can set my "early-exit" flag?  Or any other suggestions for solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [worker_shutting_down](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutting-down) signal :

```
from celery.signals import worker_shutting_down

@worker_shutting_down.connect
def worker_shutting_down_handler(sig, how, exitcode, ** kwargs):
    print(f 'worker_shutting_down({sig}, {how}, {exitcode})')
```

Dispatched when the worker begins the shutdown process. Works like a charm...

Comment: Aah no wonder I didn't see that one... I'm still on Celery 3.1... :( Looks like it's time for an upgrade :D